# How did King Manasseh and King David repent?

Tags: tanach, repentance-teshuvah

In Judaism it’s [said](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Yoma.8.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) if you sin against man you must make it right with that person, but Kings Manasseh and David didn’t, yet God accepted their Teshuva.

Comment: Menashe might have done a teshuva of sorts but according to the Gemara he didn't have a share in the World to Come.

Comment: Your question needs sources to support your claim

Comment: King Menashe also sinned directly against G-d without affecting others (idol worship), so he could repent for that.

Comment: @Dov No that's about Bat Sheva. This is about Uriah. The gemara there even says אמר רב, כי מעיינת ביה בדוד לא משכחת ביה בר מדאוריה, דכתיב (מלכים א טו, ה) "רק בדבר אוריה החתי"

Comment: N.t. Menashe sacrificed his children and affected all of Israel.

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. True, but he could do a partial teshuva.

Answer (score 2):

The Abarbanel [answers](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Samuel.12.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Abarbanel_on_II_Samuel.12.13.1&lang2=bi) your question. He explains that technically, yes, David should have gone to where Uriah was buried, but according to the Abarbanel, the sin was not made public, so taking a minyan to Uriah's grave - especially if it was, as at least one person has [suggested](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=61438&pgnum=225), near the battlefield in Ammon - would have certainly made it public and would have been a major desecration of Hashem's name (chillul Hashem). For this, Hashem accepted his repentance.

The [Kli Yakar on Kings 2:24:4](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39882&pgnum=505) points out that evidently Hashem didn't accept Menashe's repentance 100%, because the kingdom was punished later on for his sins. My understanding based on the Kli Yakar is that when it says in [Chronicles 2:23:12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.33.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) "He prayed to Him, and He granted his prayer, heard his plea, and returned him to Jerusalem to his kingdom. Then Manasseh knew that the LORD alone was God" - This refers to Menashe's sins against Hashem, not his other sins.

Comment: Baruch Shekivanti.

Answer (score 1):

2 Samuel 12:13,16-17

David said to Nathan, “I stand guilty before the LORD!” And Nathan replied to David, “The LORD has remitted your sin; you shall not die...

David entreated God for the boy; David fasted, and he went in and spent the night lying on the ground.The senior servants of his household tried to induce him to get up from the ground; but he refused, nor would he partake of food with them.

My reading: David's prayer, guilt, and fasting atoned for the sin.

Comment: So is restitution to another person a rabbinic interpretation?

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. Well, Uriah and the child of Bathsheba were both dead. Who else could David pay restitution to?

Comment: Then why the need to pay restitution.